# how can I turn off this? Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I want program's unexpected crash but this message interrupt when debugging...
how can I turn off message below??

[image]

Comment: `Debug - Start Without Debugging`?

Comment: I need attach to process debug